# How to get latest records wrt filed 'component'

Tags: sql-server

Based on component need to get the latest record where each component may have "n" of tickets but in that few will be cloned for a re-investigation purpose.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT T.* FROM my_table AS T
```

But i haven't get the perfect answer

Table will be

```
ID  Summary                         Component   Status
1   Tyre repairing                  Car         Tested
2   Glass fitting                   Bus         Tested
3   Printer repair                  Printer     Confirm
4   CLONE - Tyre Repair             Car         Tested
5   Dashboard Clean-up              Car         Confirm
6   CLONE - CLONE - Tyre Repair     Car         Tested
7   CLONE - Glass fitting           Bus         Tested
8   Cleaning                        Computer    Tested
```

Looking for output

```
ID  Summary                         Component   Status
3   Printer repair                  Printer     Confirm
5   Dashboard Clean-up              Car         Confirm
6   CLONE - CLONE - Tyre Repair     Car         Tested
7   CLONE - Glass fitting           Bus         Tested
8   Cleaning                        Computer    Tested
```

Can someone please hep me for the above?
Thanks,
Jana

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want the `Dashboard Clean-up` in the results since `car` has a later record...

Comment: No, I want that record too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need every component come just one time in result?(include with clone?)
id i understand correctly this may be help :

```
select RIGHT(Summary,len(summary)-len('CLONE -')) Summary into #t from my_table  where Summary like '%CLONE%'

select * from my_table  where Summary not in (select rtrim(ltrim(Summary)) from #t)
drop table #t
```

you can also use this veiw :

```
create view vw_InvalidSummary
as
    select RIGHT(Summary,len(summary)-len('CLONE -')) Summary from  my_table  where Summary like '%CLONE%'
```

Comment: Masoud, can't we create a view instead of temp table (#t)

Comment: of course you can, but in huge data it will be bottleneck

Comment: Understood but it contains only 500 records. Because with above query, I am going to combine with another so, View makes me easier. Could you help on view

Comment: Select query is not working seems my_table(owntable) is issue (syntax issue)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ID` column is an identity column and therefor can be used to determine which record is the latest, you can use [`top 1 with ties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and sort by [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Id, Summary, Component, Status
FROM Table
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Component, Status ORDER BY Id DESC)
```

This will return a single record for each component where the Id has the highest value for that specific component.

Comment: ID nothing but ticket number. But with your query I am able to get only one record of Component= Car but I am looking other record also of component= car

Comment: So You want the latest for each component and status?

Comment: Yes, need to see all

Comment: Then add the `Status` column to the partition by. I've edited that into my answer.